# Is there a way to ignore "/r/n" in readingContext.rawrecord while reading using CSVHelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper, blank-line

I'm parsing a comma separated text file with some empty rows using CSVhelper. CSV helper ignores empty rows when it parses the records successfully.

But when there is a missing field exception, when I look at the  `ReadingContext.RawRecord` value, it has leading "\r\n" characters from previous empty line. Is there a way to ignore this in `CSVHelper`?
I need this because even when there is an exception, I still want to get the first value to be used as Primary key to store to a database. And it fails when I have these extra characters.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure this by setting a lambda expression for Configuration.ShouldSkipRecord

```
csv.Configuration.ShouldSkipRecord = row => row[0].StartsWith("\r\n")
```